# If planar coil is used as antenna, then what kind of antenna should it belong to?

Tags: rf, antenna

The image below shows the example of planar coil I mean. In my search, I found it is similar to NFC antenna, or in the other words, loop wire antenna. However, I don't see there is a hole in the centre of the coil. By a rough definition, loop antenna can be seen as a short circuit between the two terminals of the signal feed.

So, what is the type of antenna that an arbitrary planar coil belongs to, *if it is used as an antenna*?
If I manufacture it on a PCB board, is it now a microstrip antenna? Or is there another name or definition of that kind of antenna?

(P.S. This question is more about the definition.)

[image: image1]

Comment: Is the name of vital importance here?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. This question is more about definition, categorise and name.